# Disabling static context and method invocation in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

We are currently using Thymeleaf to parse templates. We want to offer this feature to our users so that users can provide custom templates. However, Thymeleaf is very powerful and is able to call methods and access static resources.

Is there any way to disable both invoking Java methods (Or whitelist some vital calls), as well as disabling Thymeleaf from being able to access static fields and methods?

We only have to allow users to use basic IF statements, loops and accessing object fields.

Comment: Not AFAIK. Allowing users to arbitrarily inject random code into your server sounds like a recipe for disaster anyway.

Comment: IMO Thymeleaf is more of a server-side templating system; it's not something I'd normally expose to consumers, where leaner options exist, that have the data you provide, and simple operations like you describe in your question. I'm sure you could rig something up around their template execution environment, but seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: That was our concern too, Michael. I agree with that, Dave. I really don't want to have to hack around Thymeleaf because missing something could result in several major security issues. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - afraid not.

> We are currently using Thymeleaf to parse templates. We want to offer this feature to our users so that users can provide custom templates. However, Thymeleaf is very powerful and is able to call methods and access static resources.

It is, and it's designed to do so with no (secure) way that I'm aware of for disabling this functionality. Even if you could disable what you want with some kind of preprocessor hack, relying on it being watertight seems incredibly risky to me - I really wouldn't advise it. (Even if users don't access anything untoward for instance, they could still execute random code repeatedly to bog the server down and make the page load slowly.)

Instead, I'd look to the more "normal" route of exposing the functionality that users are expected to see via an endpoint that they can call via AJAX. They can then build their forms in plain old HTML / JS, making additional calls to any other resources that they need along the way.

If you're worried about extra AJAX calls, you could also statically inject a JSON object that contains everything the user may need in the header of the page - they can then display the content of that wherever they want.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we convert these templates into PDF. Using Javascript is probably not possible due to this. It is, however, important that users can include basic logic in the templates. Some of the data we provide is in lists, so it is important to be able to iterate over those. I'll look a bit further for template engines and see if one suits our needs. Thanks for your in-depth response!